# having trouble installing Laravel4 dependency with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried to install laravel4 according to the instruction in https://github.com/brunogaspar/laravel4-starter-kit.

After Downloading section I tried to do section 2 which contain:

```
    cd your-folder
    curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
    php composer.phar install
```

When I run the last command:

```
    php composer.phar install
```

I got the output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
 Installing dependencies
 - Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master bc0e1f0)
   Cloning bc0e1f0cc285127a38c6c8ea88bc5dba2fd53e94
 - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.1)
Downloading:connection...                                                              
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
 The "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/annotations/zipball/v1.1" file could not 
 be downloaded (HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error)                                    
install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev]
[--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|--verbose] 
[-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

Any idea why I got this error?

Comment: check one more time, it's probably  error with connection :)

Answer (score 1):

Relaunch the same command :

```
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: Thanks - I succeeded after few tries.